# Website starts working after a few seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I am quite new in websites and web applications. I have created a website which works correctly on localhost IIS but when I put it on server it is not working properly. I have to wait for a while until it starts working. I also get the following error when I select items in dropdown: (it's on the bottom-left corner of the window)

Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; MS-RTC LM 8)
Timestamp: Tue, 26 Mar 2013 13:07:37 UTC
Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.
Line: 869
Char: 13
Code: 0
```

I set the trace to true and it works now. But it doesn't seem to be a good solution as I still see that error when I select items in dropbox. Do you have any good suggestion for this? should I add or remove something from configuration file or somewhere else? Following is my web.cinfig

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>   
    <configuration>
     <system.web>
       <customErrors mode="Off"/>
       <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true"/>
       <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"    
                  viewStateEncryptionMode="Always"/>
       <trace
       enabled="true"/>
     </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code that is causing the exception?

Comment: When an asp.net website is first run it will take a bit of time as it compiles for the first time. As for your error. you have some javascript on the page which is throwing the error have a look in your source at line 869.

Comment: Have you used the Microsoft ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel control?

Answer (score 1):

[Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException - what it is and how to avoid it,](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx)

If you've used the Microsoft ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel control, there's a good chance you've hit the "Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException" error.

Comment: Yes I have used that. But is there any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

I actually no sure what is throwing this error. in my webform im using updatepanel. rhis is part of my web form.

```
     <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"
        Inherits="Default" %>

      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head id="Head1" runat="server">
     <title>DTC</title>
    </head>
 <body bgcolor="#333333">
 <h1 align="center" style="font-family: Arial; color: #FFFF99; height: 40px; font- 
   weight: bold;
    font-size: 50px; min-width: 900px;" title="Header">
    DTC Viewer</h1>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="margin: 50px 100px 50px 100px; min-width: 700px;
    background-color: #C0C0C0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div align="center" style="width: 100%">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="CheckboxUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table id="MainTable" runat="server" style="margin-left: 100px;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="BrandUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
                                            <asp:Label ID="BrandLabel" runat="server" Text="Brand :" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Medium"
                                                ForeColor="#333333" CssClass="MyLabel" Width="8em" 
                                                style="margin-right: 1em;text-align: right;"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="Brand" runat="server" Height="15px" Width="176px" Text="VTC" BackColor="#FFFFCC"
                                                CssClass="MyDropBox" AutoPostBack="True" ForeColor="#666666" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:Label ID="StarLabel1" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Medium"
                                                ForeColor="#333333" Width="1em" 
                                                style="text-align: left;" Text="*"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>

                                        <td style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="BrandValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Basic Search: Brand is required"
                                                ControlToValidate="Brand" InitialValue="" ForeColor="Red" Width="15em" CssClass="ErrorMessage"
                                                Font-Size="Small"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="ModelLabel" runat="server" Text="Model :" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Medium"
                                                ForeColor="#333333" CssClass="MyLabel" Width="8em" 
                                                style="margin-right: 1em;text-align: right;"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="Model" runat="server" Height="15px" Width="176px" Text="FH(4)" BackColor="#FFFFCC"
                                                CssClass="MyDropBox" AutoPostBack="True" ForeColor="#666666" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                                                 <asp:Label ID="StarLabel2" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Medium"
                                                ForeColor="#333333" Width="1em" 
                                                style="text-align: left;" Text="*"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ModelValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Basic Search: Model is required"
                                                ControlToValidate="Model" InitialValue="" ForeColor="Red" Width="15em" CssClass="ErrorMessage"
                                                Font-Size="Small"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="KTXLabel" runat="server" Text="  Emission level :" 
                                                Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Medium"
                                                ForeColor="#333333" CssClass="MyLabel" Width="8em" 
                                                style="margin-right: 1em;text-align: right; margin-left: 0px;"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="KTX" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#666666"
                                                Height="21px" Style="margin-left: 0px" Width="182px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="KTX_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                                CssClass="MyDropBox" DataTextField="text" DataValueField="value" AutoPostBack="True">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                             <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Medium"
                                                ForeColor="#333333" Width="1em" 
                                                style="text-align: left;" Text="*"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                     .........
                     ..........


         </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <div style="width: 123px; margin-left: 7px; z-index: inherit;">
        <asp:Button ID="getURLButton" runat="server" Height="32px" OnClick="getURLButton_Click"
            Text="Submit" Width="134px" BackColor="#DD5800" BorderColor="Gray" Font-Bold="True"
            Class="MyButton" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="#4E4E4E" />
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
</form>
```